# Assigning object type in plsql

Tags: oracle11g

I need your help to know how to assign the object type through a string in PLSQL
Below is the problem description:

I first created the object types as below:

```
create or replace type picu_obj is  object(Customer_ID varchar2(32767),Customer_Name varchar2(32767),Server_Name varchar2(32767),Time_stamp varchar2(32767));
create or replace type picu_obj_tab is table of picu_obj;
```

and I have a PLSQL block as below:

```
declare
 l_str1 varchar2(1000);
  l_str2 varchar2(10000);
   l_newstr1_1 varchar2(10000);
   picu_var picu_obj_tab;
   cursor c1cudetails
  is
    select item,current_value
    from
      (select rownum,
        last_value(category ignore nulls) over (order by rownum) category ,
        last_value(item ignore nulls) over (order by rownum) item,
        current_value
      from pi_perfdata_new
      order by rownum 
      )
  where upper(category) like '%CUSTOMER%DETAILS%' ;
  type cudet is table of c1cudetails%rowtype index by pls_integer;
  l_cudet cudet;
begin
/* create dynamic string for items */
  open c1cudetails;
       fetch c1cudetails bulk collect into l_cudet limit 50;
       for i in l_cudet.first..l_cudet.last loop

       l_str1:=l_str1||','||''''||l_cudet(i).current_value||'''';
       l_str2:=trim(leading ',' from l_str1);
       l_newstr1_1:='picu_obj_tab(picu_obj('||l_str2||'))';
       end loop;
      --  dbms_output.put_line(''||l_newstr1_1||'');
     -- picu_var := l_newstr1_1;
   close c1cudetails;
  end;


For the string "l_newstr1_1" following value is retruned from above PLSQL block
picu_obj_tab(picu_obj('CSCO5','DXRTYE','PI22-pro-333','2015-07-22-22:48:56'))
```

Now I want to assign the above result to variable  "picu_var"  which I have declared.

Basically I need to convert to the following during runtime.

```
picu_var := picu_obj_tab(picu_obj('CSCO5','DXRTYE','PI22-pro-333','2015-07-22-22:48:56'))
```

How to achieve the same?

Please suggest how to initialize the object type variable to the string values.

Comment: Your rownum isn't applying any real ordering, you're relying on the order that Oracle happens to return the rows. Are the item numbers(?) significant - how do you know which row in your table maps to which object attribute? Your batch suggests you can get 50 values back, which doesn't map to your 4 attributes either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dynamic PL/SQL like this:

```
execute immediate 'begin :x := ' || l_newstr1_1|| '; end;'
   using out picu_var;
```

Comment: I tried above syntax but getting    errors : ORA-06550: line 53, column 70:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "OUT" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;

Comment: I did a small correction as following and it worked            :                    execute immediate 'begin :x := ' || l_newstr1_1|| '; end;' using out picu_var;                                                                                                     Thank you very much for your help.  This answered my question  finally.